# Module not found: Can't resolve module in Next.js | Module not found: Can't resolve 'path'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

This question has been asked in StackOverFlow before, but not one correct answer is found that completely resolves the problem.

I have encountered the problem in a next.js starter application (I'm still learning).

> posts.js lib File

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import matter from "gray-matter";

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), "posts");

//The 
export function getSortedPostsData() {

//The rest of the codes...

}
```

> Error

```
./lib/posts.js:2:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'path'
  1 | import fs from "fs";
> 2 | import path from "path";
  3 | import matter from "gray-matter";
  4 | 
  5 | const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), "posts");
```

> next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack5: true,
  webpack: config => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };

    return config;
  }
};
```

Initially the error occurred in this ->

```
import fs from "fs"
```

But after adding the webpack configuration lines in the next.config.js
the error shifted to the next line in ->

```
import path from "path"
```

N.B: I have implemented getStaticProps in the index.js file that calls the aforementioned library

> index.js file

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const allPostsData = getSortedPostsData();

  return {
    props: {
      allPostsdata
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Are you using `getSortedPostsData` anywhere else in your code? Like inside a React component for instance?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes. It is called inside getStaticProps() in my Home component page, and the result from this function is returned as a prop from getStaticProps and passed down to the Home Component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do `path.join(process.cwd()`, it doesn't make sense, if you do that your path will join with the current working directory from where you're calling that script.  Instead use `path.join(__dirname, 'file')`.